# In javascript how can I get json value when key has "-"?

Tags: javascript, json

I have some json like

```
{"111-222":"AAA","333-444":"BBB"}
```

when I want to get the value of "111-222", javascript will show "Uncaught ReferenceError: 222 is not defined?

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: `obj[ "111-222" ]` try

Comment: "when I want to get the value of..."  So how are you trying to get the value?

Comment: You can only use dot notation where the key meets the parameters for an identifier. Otherwise, use square brackets. I.e. use `obj['111-222']` not `obj.111-222`.

Comment: Thanks all, I try to use obj['111-222'], and problem has resolved!